# How to pass value using httpput method in jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

I am using core java and jackson for consuming REST services. Now I need to update using HttpPut method. How to update value using this method 
My request data is like this.

```
{
  "comments": "Notes",
  "displaynumber": "AA245",
  "order": 1
}
```

I am using this type of code:

```
HttpPut httpput = new HttpPut(targetURI + "comments/1001");
httpput.setConfig(config);
httpput.addHeader("content-Type","application/json");
httpput.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

After this code how to send that Json data using jackson? And I am also using basic auth on this url.

Comment: You don't need to use jackson if you already have the JSON data in a java string variable. Here is an example of sending JSON with HttpPost. It should be almost the same using HttpPut: http://www.gnovus.com/blog/programming/making-http-post-request-json-using-apaches-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Here I am able to solve this Question answer.

```
 httpput.setEntity(new StringEntity(
    "{\"comments\":\"" + comm + "\",\"displaynumber\":\"" + tcn
      + "\",\"order\":\"" + orderAdd + "\"}",
        ContentType.create("application/json")));

 response = httpClient.execute(target, httpput);
```

For jackson we can use ObjectMapper.writeValue();